# Microsoft Identity - how to add further authentication conditions before allowing access to web app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a web app where users can log in using either:

1. Local apps accounts using local login page
2. Or Company's AAD accounts using Microsoft Idenity SSO

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

**Question**

When using SSO, I want to allow access only to those users that have local account as well (matched on username/email).

Where do I check this condition?

I thought maybe I could customize default authorization policy, but it seems too late. Ideally I would like to prevent authentication cookie to be created and send to end user.